# Make sure an IPFS file is decentralized enough and can't be unpinned

Tags: solidity, javascript, ipfs

I'd like to find a way to verify, in a smart contract, that the URI of a IPFS file is correctly distributed and should not be unpinned if the user wishes to. The idea is that a user could send a file, but should not be able, later, to have it deleted, or unpinned.

In the frontend, I'm using Web3.Storage to send the file to IPFS, and to make sure it will be available. This way, I'm sure (if I'm right) that even if I, or the user, wanted to delete it or make it unavailable, neither of us could do it. Then this URI, along with some other data, is sent to a smart contract.

The first issue is that I'm not even sure about this. Web3.Storage being a pinning service, I guess if I were to delete a file, it could be unpinned, and disappear during the following garbage collection.

Another issue is that the user could also directly call the smart contract with this data, and the URI of a file they would be the only one to pin to IPFS, and this would be valid. They could later delete it, and it would not be available anymore.

Then, here are my two questions:

1. Is there a way to make sure that a file sent to IPFS, once done, will be collected by pinning services, and wont be able to be "deleted" by any mean?
2. Also, how could it be checked that an IPFS file is correctly distributed to the network, therefore decentralized enough, in the case the URI was directly provided by the user?

Comment: Have you considered using a solution like Arweave? A file published on that network stays forever. Then you can also use the URL to the file to pin it on IPFS (there are already some services making this thing easier). For how IPFS works, a file can be always unpinned.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @70ny. I did not think about it, it's perfect for what I want to do. I can just send a copy of the file to Arweave once it's uploaded by the user, and it solves both issues!

Comment: exactly @polarzero . I suggested as this is something we have done too in the past!